# What's wrong with $\det(P) = -1$ : Change of variable for Quadric Forms ? [Kolman P552 8.7.25]

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, determinant, quadratic-forms

> Would someone please explain "why $\det(P) = 1$ is required" and the general procedure of effecting this? Lay S7.2 didn't expound on this and neither does Kolman in S8.6-8.8.

Identify the graph of 
and write in standard form $9x^2 +y^2+ 6xy - 10\sqrt{10}x + 10\sqrt{10}y + 90 = 0$.

Rewrite this as $x^TAx + Bx + f = 0$ :  $x^T \begin{bmatrix}
    9 & 3   \\
    3 & 1   \\
        \end{bmatrix} x
+ \begin{bmatrix}
    -10\sqrt{10} & -10\sqrt{10}  \\
     \end{bmatrix} x = 0.$

From symmetric A: $\lambda_1 = 0$ associates with $x_1 = (-1, 3)^T$.  $\lambda_2 = 10$ associates with $v_2 = (3, 1)^T$.

[image]

Comment: For orthogonal matrices, those with $\det P=1$ are rotations whereas those with $\det P=-1$ are reflections. Could you give some additional context though? I don't know why they require the matrix to be a rotation instead of a reflection...

Comment: @NotNotLogical Thanks. What context would you like? I'll revisit the book to see what can be added.

Comment: @LePressetiment Why does it have to be a rotation matrix? What's the point of reducing to the form shown? It would help me to know what the problem is getting at... by the way I don't know a lot of linear algebra so someone else might be more helpful.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure if this is what you are looking for, but as far as I can tell:

The question is asking you too re-write the quadratic expression in such a way that you can see what type of conic section it is and how it would be graphed.

The easiest way to do this is to write it as a rotated (ordinary) conic section. As far as the matrices go, orthogonal matrices $P$ have $\det P=\pm 1$. Those $R$ which are rotations preserve orientation, so they are the ones with $\det R=1$. Reflections have $\det R=-1$ and switch orientation, which means it would be a little harder to graph a conic from that type of representation.

You have the eigenvalues $(-1,3)^T$ and $(3,1)^T$ which, because we are dealing with quadratic forms (and hence symmetric matrices) are orthogonal as expected. Note that *any scaled eigenvalue is still an eigenvalue with the same eigenvector* (as long as you don't 'scale' by $0$). This is essentially a special case of the fact that *eigenvectors form linear subspaces.* Or algebraically, we have $$Av=\lambda v\implies A(cv)=c(Av)=c(\lambda v)=\lambda(cv)$$ so $c\mathbf{v}, c\in\mathbb{R}$ is still an eigenvector with respect to the eigenvalue $\lambda$.

---

So we have two tasks: to make a rotation matrix $R$, we have to (1) normalize the eigenbasis and (2) multiply various eigenvectors appropriately by the constant $-1$ so that the orthogonal matrix has $\det =1$ and is in fact a rotation.

After normalizing we get $$P=\begin{bmatrix}{-1\over \sqrt{10}} & {3\over \sqrt{10}} \\ {3\over \sqrt{10}} & {1\over \sqrt{10}} \end{bmatrix}$$ But this is a reflection. There are a few things we could do. We could switch the order of the eigenvalues so that the columns get switched. Or we could multiply either column by $-1$. That is how the book arrived at $$\begin{bmatrix}{1\over \sqrt{10}} & {3\over \sqrt{10}} \\ {-3\over \sqrt{10}} & {1\over \sqrt{10}} \end{bmatrix}$$ Note that multiplying *rows*, while changing the determinant, would alter the eigenvectors. But multiplying *columns*, as argued above, just produces new eigenvectors.

---

Now you complete the square to get (I believe) the equation for a parabola. You can graph the original equation by *rotating* this graph by the angle of $R$, which is in this case $\tan^{-1}{-3}\approx -72^\circ$.

Comment: yes the reason you can just multiply a column by -1, is that you are simply in effect, exchanging the "old" eigenvector with one pointing in the opposite direction but still spanning the same space. in calculating the eigenvector this is the same as using a different parameter as the independent parameter...you still get an eigenvector spanning the same space. Anyway, this is a good answer, and I think the OP should consider accepting it?

Comment: Thank you. I'm looking at lin alg now but will return to multivar calc soon. Would you please explain your third paragraph? Why "it would be a little harder to graph a conic from" a reflection? How does a reflection "switch orientation"?

Comment: Will you please to respond  in your answer, and not as comments?